# Nginx ingress controller rule to add a trailing slash to url without redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openapi, trailing-slash

The main problem client hasn't support redirection and can't generate URLs with trailing slash.

The backend uses openAPI and supports URLs only with a trailing slash. I am and kubernetes ingress in the middle. I can't change client or backend.

I am trying to rewrite the target URL on the ingress side, unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution without redirection.

I've tried solution from this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65482653/nginx-ingress-controller-rewrite-target-annotation-and-rule-to-add-a-trailing-sl), but it generate 302 code Moved Temporarily and the client can't handle this redirection.

Is it possible to rewrite the URL on nginx ingress side without redirection?

Comment: Hi Sergey and welcome! I believe Nginx will , by default try and add a trailing slash to whatever url in order to match a proper location block. I get that maybe it's not exactly what you mean but maybe you want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49768054/7120073 which is the opposite of your situation, it removes trailing slash. But i am sure it can be used wisely to add it as well. Let us know! Take care!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, described solution is some kind of redirect, that client can't handle (codes 301/302/308 are not supported on the client-side). It uses the same approach as nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target annotation.